# Recreational Math: Plots of "Roman Numerals"

Tags: plotting, function-construction, recreational-mathematics

I have been trying to solve a recreational math problem using Mathematica. Specifically, I am trying to plot the vanishing set $V_k := \{(x,y): F(x,y,k)=0\}$ for the family of functions

\begin{equation}
 F(x,y,k) := \left(\left\lfloor \frac{11}{k^2-12 k+42}\right\rfloor  (4 x+y)+8 k-28\right) \left(\left\lfloor \frac{11}{k^2-12 k+42}\right\rfloor  (4 x-y)+8 k-52\right) \left(\left\lfloor \frac{11}{k^3-22 k+127}\right\rfloor  (2 x+y)+4 k-40\right) \left(\left\lfloor \frac{11}{k^3-22 k+127}\right\rfloor  (2 x-y)+4 k-40\right) \left(\left(\lfloor \exp (k-4)\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{1}{23} \left(-x^2+10 k-8\right)\right\rfloor ^2\right) \left(\lfloor \exp (3-k)\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{\left(-\frac{5}{3} \left(k-5 \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor -2\right)^3-\frac{1}{3} \left(k-5 \left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor -2\right)-x+5\right) \left(-\frac{1}{2} \left(k-5 \left\lfloor \frac{k+1}{5}\right\rfloor -2\right)^3-\frac{3}{2} \left(k-5 \left\lfloor \frac{k+1}{5}\right\rfloor -2\right)+x-11\right)}{86400}\right\rfloor ^2\right)+\sin ^{12}\left(\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(2 \left\lfloor \frac{k-4}{5}\right\rfloor -2 k+x\right)\right)+\left\lfloor -\frac{k}{5}+\left\lfloor \frac{k}{5}\right\rfloor +1\right\rfloor \right)
\end{equation}

for $k=0,1,2,\ldots,12$. The set $V_k \cap \left\{(x,y): |y|\le 12 \right\}$ is supposed to look like the roman numeral for $k$. For instance, $V_1\cap \left\{(x,y): |y|\le 12 \right\}$ is the set $\left\{(0,y): |y|\le 12 \right\}$, and $V_{12}\cap \left\{(x,y): |y|\le 12 \right\}$ should look like ``XII.''

I have tried plotting $S_k$ using

```
ContourPlot[F[x, y, k] == .0000018, {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}]
```

for the respective values of $k$. $\epsilon = .0000018$ can be replaced with a suitably small constant (since for some reason Mathematica does not plot anything for $\epsilon = 0$). Here are pictures for what I get for $k=1,2,3,4$:

[[image: <span class=]$k=1$ case">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDuR3.png)
[[image: <span class=]$k=2$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z95to.png)
[[image: <span class=]$k=3$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrYZp.png)
[[image: <span class=]$k=4$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rG7Y.png)

It seems like the plot does not produce the correct figures for larger values of $k$. (Larger being $\ge 4$.) For instance, $k=4$ looks like a "chopped up V" instead of a "solid IV" (see figure).

Here are my questions:

1. Why do we not get anything for $\epsilon = 0$? Also the value of $\epsilon$ for which ContourPlot gives a blank picture seems to be a function of $k$. Why is this the case?
2. Why do we get the "chopping" for the larger values of $k$?
3. How can I modify the code so that we get "solid" Roman numerals?
4. After appropriate modifications from Question 3, what should the zero set $V_{13}\cap \left\{(x,y): |y|\le 12 \right\}$ look like?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Mathematica code for the definition of `F[x, y, k]`

Comment: Sometimes using a greater value of PlotPoints will fill in empty spots in a plot.